# Flash Data Post

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boa tarde pessoal.
Não estou conseguindo passar uma flash data por Post.
Quando carrego minha view eu coloco uma informação do banco na flash data:

```
 $this->session->set_flashdata('ticket_id',$dados[0]->caseId);
```

Tenho uma modal nessa view que envia as informações via post para o controller "responder".

Nesse controller, tento recuperar a flash data, mas ela está sempre vazia.

Se eu usar userdata funciona perfeitamente, com flash data não.

Minha dúvida é se por post a flash data se mantem, ou ela só pode ser recuperada após um redirect?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Fera, segundo a documentação do CodeIgniter 3.1.9.

> CodeIgniter supports “flashdata”, or session data that will only be available for the next request, and is then automatically cleared.

Ou seja, a informação setada em flashdata estará disponível somente na próxima requisição e automaticamente será excluída.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata

Acho que neste caso o certo é usar **userdata** mesmo.

Comment: Paulo, boa noite.
Exato, ela ficará disponível apenas para 1 requisição. Porém um "Post" para um controller não seria apenas 1 requisição?
View->POST->Controller

Comment: Neste caso, ficará disponível na próxima requisição. Por exemplo, se este post estiver persistindo alguma informação e logo em seguida exibir a view, irá funcionar somente com userdata. Agora, se após persistir você fizer um redirecionamento (redirect), o flashdata irá funcionar.

Comment: Perfeito Paulo.
Agora ficou claro. 
abraço